# How to add Google Workspace Marketplace Add-on to Application Launcher?

Tags: google-apps-script, workspace, add-on, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace-add-ons

I want to add my Google Workspace Marketplace Add-On to app launcher but it is only appearing in the sidebar. I have gone through the support documents but have not found anything in this regard. How do I make it appear on the application launcher as well?

The app launcher image is given below

[image: App Launcher]

The sidebar icon is shown below

[image: Sidebar icon]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

It's not possible to add Workspace add-ons to the App launcher.

#### Documentation update:

Since there's no explicit mention of this in the official documentation, I requested this to be added to the support document [Customize Google Workspace Dashboard for your users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9365414?hl=en) (bottom section `Using Dashboard or App launcher`), and also reported in Google Issue Tracker:

- [Workspace add-ons cannot be added to App launcher; add explicit mention to documentation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/200845663)

Comment: Thank you for your response. The thing is, there is already an add-on with the name of Mixmax that appears in App launcher. Have they done something differently?

Comment: @Reaper211 From what I can see, this app seems to be published as a web app, and it's the web app that is showing up, not the Workspace add-on (this limitation refers exclusively to Workspace add-ons, not just any installed app, and installed web apps to appear in the launcher).

Comment: Do web apps also appear in the sidebar?

Comment: @Reaper211 Web apps by themselves don't appear in the add-on sidebar, that's for Workspace add-ons. Technically, if an app was published as a web app **and** as a Workspace add-on, it would appear in both places (app launcher and sidebar), but I don't think you can publish an app as both (web apps can only be bundled with Drive apps or editor add-ons AFAIK).